# Two installs conflicting - Pages redirecting

Tags: multisite, redirect, slug

I have two installs of wordpress on my server.

**Site 1.** mysite.com

**Site 2.** mysite.com/othersite

The first wordpress install is located in mysite.com/wordpress, but is viewable at mysite.com, and the second install located in mysite.com/othersite, and viewable at the same address.  I have page slugs activated for both sites.

**Site 1.** works perfect. I can login to both admin panels and they work perfect.  On **Site 2.** i can view the index page, but all other pages redirect as follows:

1. redirect to the 404 page of **Site 1.**
2. if a page has a similar name in both sites e.g. mysite.com/contact and mysite.com/othersite/contact, it will redirect to the page on **Site 1.**

My guess is that something in the wordpress core files uses redirection for slugs.  But this is a stab in the dark, and i have no idea how to solve it.

Any help with this issue would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file in both the docroot and /othersite directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ignore the "otherside" in the htaccess file of your "root" blog.

You can try to add something like that above the (root) WordPress' .htaccess code:

```
# stuff to let through (ignore)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/otherside/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
#
```